# Trigger Not Running Check Whether it is correct or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

This is my trigger and its running perfectly with the help of stackoverflow.com I edit my question because of blocking.

```
USE [Online Medical Store]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_issueBook]    Script Date: 4/7/2021 11:33:13 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Trigger [dbo].[tr_issueBook] 
on [dbo].[IssueBooks] 
for insert  
AS 
Begin 
    Declare @IsbnNumber varchar 

    Select  @IsbnNumber = ISBN_Number from inserted
 
    update searchBooks set
        tbl_numberOfCopies =tbl_numberOfCopies - 1
    where tbl_IsbnBooks = @IsbnNumber
End
```

Comment: How do you know its not running? You've made the classic trigger 101 mistake of *assuming* that the `Inserted` pseudo-table has only a single row when in fact it can have 0-N and must be dealt with accordingly.

Comment: `Declare @IsbnNumber varchar ` - You didn't declare the size for `varchar` should be `varchar(10)` for example

Comment: @DaleK I did not get your point ?

Comment: @Squirrel where I declare size

Comment: When trigger fired, there might be 1 or 10 rows inserted. So `inserted` might contains more than 1 row. Your trigger query didn't handle that.

Comment: @DaleK when I insert something its not running or fire

Comment: It `DID` fire. But not updating `searchBooks`  because you have truncated `ISBN_Number ` by declaring `@IsbnNumber varchar `. If not mistaken if you don't declare the size, it is defaulted to `1`.. So there is no match

Comment: @squirrel you got my point its not updating so where I declare size ?

Comment: @DaleK Its not updating other table

Comment: Yes Thanks Guys I got it Thank You

Comment: @DaleK where I can mark this question has answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your trigger query

Issue 1. You didn't declare the size for the variable

```
Declare @IsbnNumber varchar
```

By not declaring the size, it is defaulted to `1`. So any value assign to it will be truncated

Issue 2. You are assuming the `inserted` only contains 1 single row. Which infact might contain `0` to `N` depending on the insert statement

So your statement does not handle that

```
Select  @IsbnNumber = ISBN_Number from inserted
```

Your trigger should be just simply

```
update b 
set    tbl_numberOfCopies = tbl_numberOfCopies - 1
from   inserted i
       inner join searchBooks b on b.tbl_IsbnBooks = i.ISBN_Number
```

You don't need to `declare` a variable at all in your trigger query.

---

To answer your question on the `varchar` size, you should define it like

```
Declare @IsbnNumber varchar(10)
```

assuming that the size of the `ISBNNumber` is 10